# Бот не добавляет комментарии

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, php7

В чём проблема? Бот не добавляет комментарии к записи в сообществе, к которому собственно и подключён через access_token,   доступ в типах событий на оставление комментариев я дал, использую метод wall.createComment, причём аналогичная функция отправки сообщений работает. Заранее спасибо! Ссылка на код: https://pastebin.com/B6H6M1VY

Comment: Вы добавляете комментарий к записи в сообществе? Какой код ошибки возвращает запрос?

Comment: Да, к записи в сообществе. Код состояния равен 200, а это, как я понимаю, означает успешную обработку запроса. Доступ в типах событий на оставление комментариев я дал

Comment: а `owner_id` указан со знаком `-` ?

Comment: Вот такой запрос я отправляю: api.vk.com/method/wall.createComment?owner_id=-42442064&post_id=94&message=hello&access_token=my_group_access_token&v=5.87 На выходе получаю ошибку, что нет прав доступа использовать данный метод "Access denied: no access to call this method", мне нужно получить права доступа к стене, но как это сделать, вот в чём вопрос

Comment: права доступа для приложение нужно правильно получить [ссылка](https://vk.com/dev/permissions)

Comment: у меня есть access_token для приложения через мой сайт, в параметре scope я также указал значение wall для доступа к стене, токен получал, следуя данной документации по этой ссылке: https://vk.com/dev/auth_sites, но он тоже не даёт доступ к комментированию постов в сообществе, вылезает та же ошибка

Comment: Через authcode_flow_group, scope игнорирует значение wall

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101386/discussion-between-amadeus246-and--).

Comment: @РустамГимранов в тексте вопроса есть ссылка на код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, просто получив универсальный `access_token` в самом сообществе, отметив все пункты.

Также я отредактировал запрос для сервера в моём коде, чтобы бот отвечал на комментарии пользователям, которые напишут их под любым постом в группе. А вот и сам рабочий запрос:

> **api.vk.com/method/wall.createComment?owner_id=-group_id&reply_to_comment='.$reply_id.'&'. $get_params_comm**, *где*

- `group_id` - `id` группы,
- `reply_to_comment` - параметр для ответа на комментарии,
- `reply_id` - переменная, в которую записывается `id` комментария,
- `get_params_comm` - переменная, в которой содержатся остальные параметры для сервера, такие как:

  - `access_token` - ключ сообщества
  - `v` - версия API, которую вы используете.

Или можете просто посмотреть код, он обновлён:

```
<?php

//ключ группы, который мы должны вернуть серверу VK API
$group_token = 'beb...';

//функция отправки сообщений
function vk_msg_send($peer_id, $text_msg)
{
  // $randomID_v1 = mt_rand(20, 99999999);
  // $randomID_v2 = rand().time();

  //запрашиваем и отправляем параметры серверу
  $request_params_msg = array(
    'message' => $text_msg,
    'random_id' => rand().time(),
    'peer_id' => $peer_id,
    'access_token' => "access_group_token",
    'v' => '5.103'
  );
  $get_params_msg = http_build_query($request_params_msg);
  file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'. $get_params_msg);
}

//функция отправки комментариев
function vk_new_comm($post_id, $reply_id, $text_comm)
{
  //запрашиваем и отправляем параметры серверу
  $request_params_comm = array(
    'post_id' => $post_id,
    'id' => $reply_id,
    'message' => $text_comm,
    'access_token' => "access_group_token",
    'v' => '5.103'
  );
  $get_params_comm = http_build_query($request_params_comm);
  file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.createComment?owner_id=-4244....&reply_to_comment='.$reply_id.'&'. $get_params_comm);
}

/*создаём переменную, в которой будем получать данные (запрос) от пользователя (через VK API) в виде JSON-файла и декодировать (переводить) их в обычный php
 *в дальнейшем трансформируем (производим какие-то действия с этими данными), переводим обратно в JSON-формат и отправляем их VK API, а он уже формирует окончательный ответ для пользователя
 */
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

//ловим тип данных (события), которые нам отправляет сервер VK API
switch ($data->type) {

  //отправляем ответ VK API на запрос 'confirmation' в виде нашего ключа из переменной "group_token" для установки связи с сервером
  case 'confirmation':
    echo $group_token;
    break;

  /*подключаемся к событию "message_new"
     *ловим и проверяем сообщения
     */
  case 'message_new':
    $message_text = $data -> object -> text;
    $chat_id = $data -> object -> peer_id;
    $id_random = $data -> object -> random_id;

    // если переменная "message_text" (сообщение пользователя) будет равна указанному нами строковому значению, тогда мы будем отправлять пользователю строковый ответ через переменную "chat_id"
    if ($message_text == "привет" || $message_text == "Привет") {
      vk_msg_send($id_random, $chat_id, "Привет");
    } elseif ($message_text == "пока" || $message_text == "Пока") {
      vk_msg_send($id_random, $chat_id, "Пока");
    } else {
      vk_msg_send($id_random, $chat_id, "Ты что-то сказал?");
    }

    //отвечаем этим сообщением на все запросы сервера VK API, чтобы подтвердить, что всё сработало верно и всё ОК
    echo 'ok';
    break;

  /*подключаемся к событию "wall_reply_new"
     *ловим и проверяем комментарии
     */
  case 'wall_reply_new':
    $comment_text = $data -> object -> text;
    $id_post = $data -> object -> post_id;
    $comm_id = $data -> object -> id;

    // если переменная "comment_text" (комментарий пользователя) будет равна указанному нами строковому значению, тогда мы будем отправлять пользователю строковый ответ через переменные "post_id" - id поста и "id" - id комментария
    if ($comment_text=="привет" || $comment_text=="Привет" || $comment_text=="ПРИВЕТ" || $comment_text=="ghbdtn" || $comment_text=="Ghbdtn" || $comment_text=="GHBDTN") {
      vk_new_comm($id_post, $comm_id, "Hello");
    }

    //отвечаем этим сообщением на все запросы сервера VK API, чтобы подтвердить, что всё сработало верно и всё ОК
    echo 'ok';
    break;
}
```